# JS 0 === (0 || 6); returns false - why?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, equality, conditional-operator

```
0 === (0 || 6) // returns false
false === (false || 6) // returns false
(false === false || false === 6) // returns true
(0 === 0 || 0 === 6) // returns true
```

```js
console.log( 0 === (0 || 6) );
console.log( false === (false || 6) );
console.log( (false === false || false === 6) );
console.log( (0 === 0 || 0 === 6) );
```

what gives?  I ran across this scenario earlier and don't get it.

Comment: _`"(0 === 0 || 0 === 6)` returned true"_. What on earth did you expect?

Comment: `(0 || 6)` evaluates to `6`. As such, `0 === 6` will of course return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
0 === (0 || 6) // returns false
```

It's all about order of operations. That returns false because the parenthesis are evaluated first. So `(0 || 6)` returns 6 and `0 === 6` is `false`

```
false === (false || 6) // returns false

(false === false || false === 6) // returns true

(0 === 0 || 0 === 6) // returns true
```

The rest are easy to follow after that explanation.

Comment: For extra clarification if you're really confused, `(0 || 6) === 6` because 0 is falsy. So (0 || 6) in this case is logically equivalent to (false || true).

Comment: @lukeic Perhaps I'm just not following your explanation, but `(0 || 6)` is not equivalent to `(false || true)`. The first returns `6`, the second returns `true`. `6 !== true`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Type-wise yes, `6` is a number and `true` is a boolean and therefore `6 !== true`. However, what I was getting at was that when looking at `(0 || 6)` as a logical statement – i.e. if 0 is true, then the statement is true. or if 6 is true, then the statement is true – it may help to look at it as the statement `(false || true)` instead, as `0` is considered falsy and 6 isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`0 === (0 || 6)` is equivalent to `0 === 6` which is of course false.

`false === (false || 6)` is equivalent to `false === 6` which is also obviously false.

`(false === false || false === 6)` is equivalent to `true || false` which is of course true.

`(0 === 0 || 0 === 6)` is also equivalent to `true || false`.

Look up "operator precedence". That'll help you wrap your head around javascript in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know the operators priority.

Second, you should know how the operators work and what they return.

[Here is the documentation you can take it as reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

```js
console.log( 0 === (0 || 6) );
// (0 || 6) returns 6 because 0 is falsy,
// so it becomes 0 === 6. It is obviously return false.

console.log( false === (false || 6) );
(false || 6) is equals (0 || 6), so we get (false === 6) = false.

console.log( (false === false || false === 6) );
// this is three part. === is prior to ||, 
// so we should do (false === false) and (false === 6).
// (false === false) is true and (false === 6) is false,
// so we get (true || false) = true

console.log( (0 === 0 || 0 === 6) );
// (0 === 0) is true and (0 === 6) is false,
// so true || false is true.
```

> By the way, most of the JavaScript operator do **type conversion**
> whether the two sides is not the type the operator want.
> Here's something you can take a look:
>
> https://javascript.info/type-conversions

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I am guessing you are not familiar with how `AND` & `OR` are used or works.

So,

`|` stands for bitwise `OR`

and, `&` stands for bitwise `AND`

It is a common method of writing `AND` as `&&` and `OR` as `||`.

For `AND`, following are the scenarios:

```
 1 && 1 => 1
 1 && 0 => 0
 0 && 1 => 0
 0 && 0 => 0
```

For `OR`, following are the scenarios:

```
 1 || 1 => 1
 1 || 0 => 1
 0 || 1 => 1
 0 || 0 => 0
```

In the above, `1` can be any non-zero integer or value (but we denote it by one, meaning **high**).

So, if you write,

`0 === ( 0 || 6 )`,

then, `( 0 || 6 )` is already `true`, then, if you compare `true` with `0`, then it is always going to be false.

Whereas, if you you change the above condition as:

`0 == ( 0 && 6 )`, (**EDITTED**)

`( 0 && 6 )` becomes false, and then `0 == false` becomes `true`.

`===` and `==` are different because the second one just checks if they are equal or not, but it does not check if they are exactly same. `===` checks if the values are identical, meaning exactly same.

I hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: `0 === false` becomes `true`? What are you talking about?

Comment: @TerryWei thanks for pointing out my mistake, I have updated my answer, please check if there are any other silly mistakes in my answer. Thanks.